# Creating a desktop .url shortcut with an icon

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a simple script to as part of a deployment to multiple sites that will create a desktop shortcut to a web address and apply an icon to it, but I'm running into some errors.

Here's the script:

```
# region Functions
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot

# Initial values
$Icon_start_path = ".\Icon.ico"
$Icon_end_folder = "C:\Program Files\Icons"
$Icon_end_path = "C:\Program Files\Icons\Icon.ico"
$Shortcut_end_path = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\website.url"
$Target_path = "https://website.co.uk/"
$Icon_filename = "Icon.ico"

# If previous shortcut is there, delete it
Get-ChildItem $Shortcut_end_path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Check if icon file has been copied to $Icon_end_folder
if (Test-Path $Icon_end_folder) {
   
    Write-Host "Icons folder already exists."
    
}
else
{
  
    #Create directory if it doesn't exists
    New-item -Path $Icon_end_folder -ItemType Directory
    Write-Host "Icons folder created."
}

# Copy the icon file over
Copy-Item -Path $Icon_start_path -Destination $Icon_end_folder

# Create the shortcut
$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut_end_path)
$shortcut.TargetPath = $Target_path
$Shortcut.IconLocation = $Icon_end_path
$shortcut.Save()
```

When I test run it in Powershell, I'm getting the following error messages:

```
The shortcut pathname must end with .lnk or .url.
At line:2 char:1
+ $shortcut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut_end_path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
The property 'TargetPath' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:3 char:1
+ $shortcut.TargetPath = $Target_path
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
The property 'IconLocation' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:4 char:1
+ $Shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\Program Files\NHS_Icons\CSMS.ico"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:1
+ $shortcut.Save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Despite this, it does everything correctly - creates the folder, copies the .ico over, creates a functioning .url on the desktop - but the error message seems to be implying that it can't find the correct web address to assign to the shortcut. Everything after that looks to be saying that it doesn't know what to do with the commands after that because the shortcut's not been created properly / yet.

If that can all be ignored, fine, but the last thing I can't get working is the .ico being applied to the shortcut. Can anyone suggest a solution for me, please?

Comment: Since an URL file is only a text file with a certain ID in it I'd recommend to use a here string you write to a newly created `*.url` file. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be enough. At least it works for me. ‍♂️

```
$URLFileContent = @'
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,11
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
URL=https://website.co.uk/
IconIndex=0
HotKey=0
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Icons\Icon.ico
'@


$NewItemSplat = @{
    Path     = 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop'
    Name     = 'website.url'
    ItemType = 'File'
    Value    = $URLFileContent
    Force    = $true
}
New-Item @NewItemSplat
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that your code worked, given the error messages:

- The first error message implies that the value of `$Shortcut_end_path` didn't actually end in `.url`
- The follow-up errors can be explained by `$shortcut` - due to the failed `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut()` call - containing `$null` and `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher being in effect.

---

If you *do* pass a `$Shortcut_end_path` path ending in `.url`, in order to create a *URL* shortcut, what [`(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//xsy6k3ys(v=vs.85)) returns is a [`WshUrlShortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/265a4017.aspx) instance (whereas creating a *regular* shortcut (`.lnk`) returns a [`WshShortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k.aspx) instance).

Unlike with `WshShortcut`, **the *only* writeable property of a `WshUrlShortcut` instance is `.TargetPath`** - curiously, **`.IconLocation` is absent**.

However, unlike `.lnk` files, which are binary, **`.url` files are INI-format *plain-text files***, so you have two options:

- You can **write the *entire* `.url` file as plain text yourself**, as shown in [Olaf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77366725/45375).
- You can ***append* the icon information to the `.url` file after the fact:**

  ```
  # Be sure to use *full paths
  $urlShortcutPath = "$HOME\Desktop\website.url"
  $url = 'https://example.org'
  $iconPath = 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDrive.ico'

  # Create the shortcut
  $urlShortcut = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($urlShortcutPath)
  $urlShortcut.TargetPath = $url
  $urlShortcut.Save()

  # Append the icon information.
  'IconIndex=0', "IconFile=$iconPath" |
    Add-Content -LiteralPath $urlShortcutPath
  ```

Alternatively, if you want a ***fully* API-based solution**, you can **use a regular `.lnk` file**:

- `.lnk` file shortcuts too can accept URLs in their `.TargetLocation` property and *do* have an `.IconLocation` property
- The only caveat is that you won't be able to edit the shortcut's target URL *interactively* after the fact.

  ```
   # Be sure to use *full paths
   # Note the use of *.lnk
   $shortcutPath = "$HOME\Desktop\website.lnk"
   $url = 'https://example.org'
   $iconPath = 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDrive.ico'

   # Create the shortcut
   $shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)
   $shortcut.TargetPath = $url
   # Now you can use .IconLocation
   $shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath
   $shortcut.Save()
  ```